# How to save one signal player id in react native state

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, react-native, onesignal

I am new to react native, I am using one signal for notification. I got one signal users player id from `OneSignal.configure();` this and by following code which I have done but that player id which I can see only on console. I am using `setState` to save in state but it is showing error that `setState is not a function`. How can I get that player id to save it in state.

code:

```
componentWillMount() {
          OneSignal.init("d447e6e2-0c8e-4781-8292-6e77d2e86691");

          OneSignal.configure();
          OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
          OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
          OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
          OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
          OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
          OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
      }

      onReceived(notification) {
          console.log("Notification received: ", notification);
      }

      onOpened(openResult) {
        console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
        console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
        console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
        console.log('openResult: ', openResult);
      }

      onIds(device) {
        console.log('Device info: ', device);
      console.log('player id: ', device.userId);
       this.setState({
            pid: device.userId,
          })
       console.log(this.state.pid);
      }
```

Comment: use `bind`. `OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds.bind(this));`

Comment: @azium yehh thank you so much. its working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event listeners functions doesn't know your `this` so you have to use `bind` to take your `this` inside them.

```
componentWillMount() {
    OneSignal.init('ONESIGNAL-APP-ID');

    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived.bind(this));
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened.bind(this));
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds.bind(this));
    OneSignal.configure();
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also declare as arrow functions to avoid .bind(this):

```
componentWillMount() {
    OneSignal.init('ONESIGNAL-APP-ID');

    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
    OneSignal.configure();
}

onReceived = () => {}
onOpened = () => {}
onIds = () => {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get player id in this way too:

```
const data = await OneSignal.getDeviceState();

const player_id=data.userId;
```

Reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72224052/5783617

Answer (score 0):

if you are using new Onesignal version then follow this code

```
OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optIn()
        OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.addEventListener('change', (subscription) => {
            console.log(subscription?.current?.id)
        });
```

After that clear your app cache or uninstall your app and then run